# Under Netbeans/Java Swing, how do I run the program as GTK+ Look and Feel?

Tags: java, linux, swing, gtk, look-and-feel

I've been trying to Google this answer with no results. I keep on finding answers on how to make Netbeans run in a GTK skin .... this is NOT what I want.

I have a Java Swing application.  I can preview it under GTK+, C/X Motif perfectly fine when I right click the JPanel Form --> Preview.  However, whenever I try to run the program (build + run), the resulting GUI is a Java Swing look and feel.

How do I permanently enable GTK+ for this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [set the Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) according to the native look and feel.

The following code must be ran when your app starts up.

```
public static void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Netbeans is Complaining that I don't have UIManager.  What packages do I import?

Comment: The package is `javax.swing`.

Answer (score 0):

In Projects explorer right click on project node, select Properties, go to Application -> Desktop App node, select desired Look & Feel

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response! I'm using Netbeans 6.9 on a Linux Platform and I can't seem to find the Desktop App Node.  Under Applications-> Desktop (I only see Web Start and Formatting).

Are you on a different flavor?

Comment: This might be available only for Netbeans Platform applications